# Ruby On Rails: form_for label and text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have the following for:

```
<%= form_for Ggroup.new, url: what_to_do_files_path ,method: :get ,:validate => true do |f| %>
<div class="field_label">
<%= f.label :group_name%>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%=f.text_field :group_name %>
</div>
<%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-primary", :name => 'submit' do %> Submit <% end %>
lalala
<%end%>
```

So I have following structure: 
`Group name` `the field for typing`. 

I would like to have the label inside the the field for typing. So that the words "Group name" would be not near the text field but inside it and the user will type his group name there.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the name of the functionality you are looking for is **placeholder**.
You can implement a placeholder for textfield like this,

```
<%=f.text_field :group_name, placeholder: "Group Name" %>
```